# Flutter Swift StreamHandler handle multiple listeners

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

I'm create a flutter plugin and need to write a stream handler that can handle multiples listeners.

Right now the `FlutterStreamHandler` requires two functions to be implemented. I store the `FlutterEventSink` instance in an array. So that when the `onConnectionStateChanged` is called I can forward it to all listeners.

```dart
class ConnectionStateStreamHandler: NSObject, DeviceConnectionDelegate, FlutterStreamHandler {
    var plugin: WearablePlugin? = nil
    var eventSinks: [FlutterEventSink] = []
    
    func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
        self.eventSinks.append(events)
        return nil
    }

    func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
        // how to cancel/remove the old eventSink that is now closed?
        return nil
    }
    
    func onConnectionStateChanged(device: Device, connectionState: ConnectionState) {
        let data = try! jsonEncoder.encode(device)
        self.eventSinks.forEach({ $0(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)) })
    }
}
```

The problem is how to remove the right `FlutterEventSink` when the `onCancel` is called? I'm not a swift programmer but can't figure out how to do this.